# CUDA transpose More Than one Thread

Tags: cuda

im trying to do transpose square matrix using tiling (blocks method) via CUDA, i have successfuly done it but onnly when entering one thread per dimension , as below in the Host function :

```
dim3 dimGrid((nEven + TILE_DIM - 1) / TILE_DIM, (nEven + TILE_DIM - 1) / TILE_DIM, 1);
dim3 dimBlock(1, 1, 1);
```

considering : nEven size of matrix + TILE_DIM is the tile size block
i have really trouble into understanding how the threads work in GPU, so ive managed to code as the below my kernel which works with only one thread per block :

```
__global__ void transposeMain(int *idata)
{
__shared__ int tile2[TILE_DIM][TILE_DIM ];

int yy = blockIdx.y * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.y;
int xx = blockIdx.x * TILE_DIM + threadIdx.x;


if (xx < nEven && yy < nEven)
{

for (int i = 0; i < TILE_DIM; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j++)
tile[i][j] = idata[(i + xx)*nEven + (j + yy)];

__syncthreads();

for (int i = 0; i < TILE_DIM; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < TILE_DIM; j++){

temp1 = tile[i][j];
                idata[(j + yy)*nEven + (i + xx)] = temp1;

}

}
```

Please help me how can i manage more than one threads into my tiling, as i feel im missing something , i tried many ways but it keeps getting out of bound memory and gives wrong data,
many thanks

Comment: This [blog](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread in a block represents a value in range `[0..TILE_DIM-1]`, in both x and y dimention. Thus, a single instruction working with `xx` and `yy` will cover the whole area in your tile. There is no need for additional `for` loops.

Comment: okay got it @cygnus thax, i altered the code but i  am facing another problem if its ok to ask, the code is working but only at limited sizes,meaning once i test Tile = 32 + size square 160 x 160, it just works on have the matrix not the total matrix, if i lower the size of matrix it works fine, i re post code above, pls any ideas why ?

Comment: , @robert in the blog given thanks for it , but can you clarify why they use "  BLOCK_ROWS = 8" constant ? i didnt get this point at all, the idea is to copy 32 data into tile array, why loop with +8 row? pls advise, many thanks

Comment: It is not good to edit your questions by applying an answer to it, because when someone 3rd sees the question, the answer becomes obsolete/wrong/detached. If you have a follow-up question, just ask a new question.

Comment: ok thanks for the point will redo the code to origin and ask new question - didnt figure how to put new code here, il open new question. thank you